# Type-casting sender vs. using object's ID

Tags: c#, events

In the event of a known object, is it better practice to refer to the object by its ID or by casting the sender to the object type?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="customBTN" OnClick="customBTN_Click" Text="Click Me" />
```

**By ID:**

```
protected void customBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customBTN.Text = "Clicked.";
}
```

*vs.*

**Type-casting:**

```
protected void customBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Text = "Clicked.";
}
```

I'm assuming referencing by ID is probably better since no cast is involved, but wonder if maybe it's considered better practice to use the sender object in event handling.

Comment: casting would be useful, if you have multiple buttons attached to a single event, and you want to know at run time, what button was clicked, otherwise it is useless.

Comment: @Habib - didn't read your comment before posting my answer - but the same thought was going through my mind too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, reference by ID is better.

The reason is not because it doesn't involve casting, rather its easier to understand when you refer the control name and it clearly states your are going to work only with the a particular button.

You can consider casting if this is going to be something generic and can be bound to multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (however unlikely - but could happen):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="customBTN" OnClick="customBTN_Click" Text="Click Me" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="custom1BTN" OnClick="customBTN_Click" Text="Click Me" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="custom2BTN" OnClick="customBTN_Click" Text="Click Me" />
```

Many buttons subscribing to the same event - your second example would change the text of the button without knowing which button was clicked, whereas the first is explicit and clear what your intentions are.

Further to this, in your second example, you would need a way of discriminating which button was actually pressed, so you would `(sender as Control).ID` to get the ID value and perform some logic on this value.